# File upload using dropzon.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dropzone.js

I'm trying to upload files using dropzone.js

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveMethod", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "dropzone", id = "js-upload-form" }))
........................
 <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" name="MainFile" id="js-upload-files"/>                    
                </div>
                <div class="upload-drop-zone" id="drop-zone">
                    Just drag and drop files here
                </div>
                <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 var formData = null;
  formData = new FormData($form[0]);

  dropZone.ondrop = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.className = 'upload-drop-zone';

            startUpload(e.dataTransfer.files)
        }

        dropZone.ondragover = function () {
            this.className = 'upload-drop-zone drop';
            return false;
        }

        dropZone.ondragleave = function () {
            this.className = 'upload-drop-zone';
            return false;
        }   
       var startUpload = function (files) {            
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
        }            
    }
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult SaveMethod(TaskManage objTaskManage, HttpPostedFileBase files)
 {
 }
```

Now, after submit, i want to have files that was dropped on drop area along with the files attached in upload control. Here, what happens is *files* giving me null and when i use Request.Files["MainFile"] i get only the files dropped on dropzone area, it doesn't show me the file i have upload to control.

I'm not able to find out the issue. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**File upload in ASP.NET MVC using Dropzone JS and HTML5**

You can download the latest version from the official site here http://www.dropzonejs.com/ and also we can install using the nuget package manage console by the following command Package Manager Console

```
PM> Install-Package dropzone
```

[image]

Now create a bundle for your script file in BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/dropzonescripts").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/dropzone/dropzone.js"));
```

Similarly add the dropzone stylesheet in the BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/dropzonescss").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/dropzone/css/basic.css",
                     "~/Scripts/dropzone/css/dropzone.css"));
```

Now add the bundle reference in your _Layout page
[image]

**View Page:**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <form action="~/Home/SaveUploadedFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm" style="width: 50px; background: none; border: none;">
        <div class="fallback">
            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile()
{
        bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;
        string fName = "";
                try{
        foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
            //Save file content goes here
            fName = file.FileName;
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                var originalDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format("{0}Images\\WallImages", Server.MapPath(@"\")));

                string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "imagepath");

                var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString);

                if (!isExists)
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

                var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString, file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);

            }

        } 

       }
       catch(Exception ex)
        {
            isSavedSuccessfully = false;
        }


        if (isSavedSuccessfully)
        {
            return Json(new { Message = fName });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { Message = "Error in saving file" });
        }
 }
```

Now add the following script to your view page at the and in script tag.

```
//File Upload response from the server
        Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {
            init: function () {
                this.on("complete", function (data) {
                    //var res = eval('(' + data.xhr.responseText + ')');
                     var res = JSON.parse(data.xhr.responseText);
                });
            }

        };
```

Here you can see the response from server.